# Propagating Model#save across all ActiveModel associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

I have the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :blog
end

class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

If I do this:

```
@user = User.new
@blog = Blog.new

@blog.title = 'hi'
@user.blog = @blog

@user.save
```

Why/how is it saving the `@blog` object to the database without me saving the `@blog` object?
For example, If I continue from the above example:

```
@user.reload
@user.blog.title
#=> 'hi'
```

It magically has saved `@blog` to the db!

Strangely, if my `@blog` has other associations, it doesn't seem to save them to the database.

What's the general behavior/logic behind that? My `@blog` has other associations and I'd like to be able to simply call `@user.save` and have it save *all* associations. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is that associations are "autosaved" when the `autosave` option is not specified, i.e. the `autosave` option is by default is `true` with the condition of "new association records are saved but the updated associations are not saved".

The following description taken from the Rails API docs on "[Active Record Autosave Association](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html)" explains this feature clearly:

> AutosaveAssociation is a module that takes care of automatically
>   saving associated records when their parent is saved. In addition to
>   saving, it also destroys any associated records that were marked for
>   destruction. (See mark_for_destruction and marked_for_destruction?).
>
> Saving of the parent, its associations, and the destruction of marked
>   associations, all happen inside a transaction. This should never leave
>   the database in an inconsistent state.
>
> If validations for any of the associations fail, their error messages
>   will be applied to the parent.
>
> Note that it also means that associations marked for destruction won't
>   be destroyed directly. They will however still be marked for
>   destruction.
>
> Note that autosave: false is not same as not declaring :autosave. When
>   the :autosave option is not present then new association records are
>   saved but the updated association records are not saved.

If you do not want the associated objects saved or destroyed when parent objects are created/updated or destroyed then specify `autosave: false` when declaring associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :blog, autosave: false
end
```

This way, when an `user` is created, you won't see it's associated `blog` saved.  You'll have to save it manually calling `save` on the associated `blog` instance.